# Use .scss filename to determine gulp's output path

Tags: javascript, gulp, directory-structure

Let's say I have the following directory structure:

```
project
│
├destination
│ ├abc
│ │ └style.css
│ ├def
│ │ └style.css
│ └ghi
│   └style.css
│
├scss
│ ├abc.scss
│ ├def.scss
│ └ghi.scss
│
├gulpfile.js
...
```

Is there a way, using gulp, to accept the name of the scss file being watched, and use it as a means to determine the output path? So, when saving `ghi.scss`, the result would be `destination/ghi/style.css`?

I've tried using the gulp-filenames dependency, but my experience with gulp is very limited.

My current gulp file is as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var filenames = require("gulp-filenames");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'watch']);
```